# 3 Table Join in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Say I have 3 tables. Table1 contains client_id and client_name. Table2 contains client_id, client_catid_1, and client_catid_2. These to tables are joined based on the, client_id. Now the third table, contains category_id and category_name. How can join the third table based on the category id's and get the category_name? example:

**Table 1:**

```
client_id | client_name
-----------------------
121231231 | Some name
345234666 | Another Name
-----------------------
```

**Table 2:**

```
client_id | client_catid_1 | client_catid_2
-------------------------------------------
121231231 | 22             | 79
345234666 | 34             | 566
------------------------------------------
```

**Table 3:**

```
category_id | category_name
----------------------------
22          | category 22
34          | category 34
79          | category 79
566         | category 566
----------------------------
```

**Then the output:**

```
client_id | client_name | client_cat1 | client_cat2
---------------------------------------------------
121231231 | Some name   | category 22 | category 79
345234666 | Another     | category 34 | category 566
---------------------------------------------------
```

**And the current query:**

```
SELECT client.*,
cat1id.client_catid_1 as cat1,
cat2id.client_catid_2 as cat2
FROM tb_clients AS client
LEFT JOIN tb_clients_categories cat1id ON client.client_id = cat1id.client_id
LEFT JOIN tb_clients_categories cat2id ON client.client_id = cat2id.client_id
WHERE client.client_id = 65447
```

Also, I am not asking about database normalization or design. I only say this because people tend to miss your question and start trying to inform you of better database design. I understand this. I am working with something I did not originally put together and changing the DB is not an option!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT a.client_id,
          a.client_name,
          c1.category_name AS client_cat1,
          c2.category_name AS client_cat2
     FROM tb_clients a
LEFT JOIN tb_clients_categories b ON b.client_id = a.client_id
LEFT JOIN TABLE C c1 ON c1.category_id = b.client_catid_1
LEFT JOIN TABLE C c2 ON c2.category_id = b.client_catid_2
    WHERE c1.category_name = 'Something' 
       -- because you can't refer to a column (client_cat1) alias in the WHERE
```

That will give you a list of clients, and optionally their category names.  If a relationship does not exist between `tb_clients_categories` and `tb_clients`, the client name will still appear and the `client_cat1` and `client_cat2` will be null.  If you don't want this, remove the `LEFT` keyword on the JOINs for only clients with two categories associated to appear in the output.

Comment: This is perfect but one question... Is it possible to say: WHERE client_cat1 = 'Something' ?

Comment: PERFECT! Thats what had me stumped. I kept getting "unkown column". Thanks!

Comment: @mike: You can refer to a column alias in the `ORDER BY`, but not typically anywhere else... unless this is a subquery.

Comment: @OMG Ponies , I have the same requirement and used left join for that and getting the results as expected .But its taking hell lot of time.What i can i do to optimize this.?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT client.*,
cat1id.client_catid_1 as cat1,
cat1id.client_catid_2 as cat2,
cat1.category_name,
cat2.category_name
FROM tb_clients AS client
LEFT JOIN tb_clients_categories cat1id ON client.client_id = cat1id.client_id
LEFT JOIN category cat1 ON category.cat_id = cat1id.client_catid_1
LEFT JOIN category cat2 ON category.cat_id = cat2id.client_catid_2
WHERE client.client_id = 65447
```

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` statement can contain any filter. Use `OR` in the join clause and you do not need to repeat the first table.:

```
SELECT client.*,
  cats.category_id AS client_catid
FROM tb_clients AS client
  LEFT JOIN tb_clients_categories cat1id ON client.client_id = cat1id.client_id
  LEFT JOIN tb_categories cats ON 
    (cats.category_id = cat1id.client_cat1 OR 
     cats.category_id = cat1id.client_cat2)
WHERE client.client_id = 65447
```

Comment: This will return two rows per `client_id`, if both categories exist.